# Need to create a loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to create a loop that will redo my query over and over until it posts something in the database.

```
if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
        $person = $row['firstname'];
        $taken = $row['taken'];

        if (isset($_COOKIE[$firstname])) {
            echo "You've already drawn " . $_COOKIE[$firstname] . "!";
        } else {
            if (($person == ucfirst($firstname)) || ($taken == 1)) {
                echo 'Redraw';
            } else {
                echo ucfirst($firstname) . " drew $person!";
                setcookie($firstname, $person, time() + 30);
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Query Failed';
}
```

Instead of echo 'Redraw'; I need it to auto run a loop again because once they click the button the button is disabled.

I was thinking do while, but I cannot get it to work properly.

Comment: Can you please put your entire function? It is missing a lot of }

Comment: please don't use mysql_* use mysqli_* or pdo instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be accomplished like this:

```
while (true) {
    if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            $person = $row['firstname'];
            $taken = $row['taken'];

            if (isset($_COOKIE[$firstname])) {
                echo "You've already drawn " . $_COOKIE[$firstname] . "!";
                break;
            } else {
                if (($person == ucfirst($firstname)) || ($taken == 1)) {
                    // loop will continue
                } else {
                    echo ucfirst($firstname) . " drew $person!";
                    setcookie($firstname, $person, time() + 30);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Query Failed';
        break;
    }

}
```

But I'm not sure what its supposed to do. Most probably you meant something different.